# How to set default label color based on dark/light mode (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode

I am trying to update my iOS app for dark mode, but am having trouble with setting the dark mode colors in code. Upon editing a UITextView, the color I want the text color to be white in dark mode, and black in light mode (which is default label color), but to my knowledge I do not know how to write this in code, how do I do it?

```
extension AddCardsVC: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            definitionInput.textColor = UIColor.(need default label color)
        } else {
            definitionInput.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
        if(definitionInput.text == "organizing items into familiar, manageable units; often occurs automatically"){
            definitionInput.text = ""
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   textView.textColor =  UIColor { tc in
            switch tc.userInterfaceStyle {
            case .dark:
                return UIColor.white
            default:
                return UIColor.black
            }
        }
```

This is the easiest way, the UIColor can be passed a closure with traitCollection (TC) and the traitCollection has a property called userInterfaceStyle which tells if the user is using the dark mode, then you just implement switch statement to choose what color you wanna return

Answer (score 24):

Or use `UIColor.label` to get system label color.

Answer (score 10):

you have call this line of code , it works fine both dark mode and light mode.
goodluck

label.textColor = .none

Comment: This works great for UILabels as the documentation says : The default value for this property is the system’s label color, which adapts dynamically to Dark Mode changes.
However it does NOT work for me for a UITextView, documentation : The default text color is black.

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.textColor =  .placeholderText
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation for why this addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to assign UIColor.systemBackground to your UITextView Text Color

```
textView.textColor =  UIColor.systemBackground
```

it will automatically change text color white in dark mode and text color black in light mode

Comment: You have it opposite. This would make the text white in light mode, and dark in dark mode....